# Escape Character In URL, not able to login

Tags: java, selenium

I need to visit a link that pops up username and PWD. I tried bypassing it with

```
http://username:password@the-site.com
```

I am able to log in without a popup screen but if my PWD starts # like
#applicationx
It is redirecting to something else.

How can I resolve this issue for users with PWD starting with #

I tried using escape, still not getting it.
Edit :
This is how i did, with john be username and #appname as pwd

```
http://john:\#appname@the-site.com
```

Comment: Show us the code how have you tried it ?

Comment: @cruisepandey please check now

Comment: I meant your code ?

Comment: @cruisepandey there is no code  , I am trying to reach a URL which has username and pwd , and i am trying to bypass it by using this -> 
 "http://username:password@the-site.com "
But when the pwd has special characters , it is not going to the site

Comment: Try `http://john:%23appname@the-site.com`